# AJAX Request is not working in PHP switch statement

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm having problems with a PHP switch statement receiving an AJAX request, so I'd like to give some info and then pose my question:

First, I've looked through dozens upon dozens of answers here and elsewhere without success on this issue. I recently upgraded from PHP5 to PHP7 on my home server, because I upgraded my OS from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 16.04.2 (command line install only). My HTML/jQuery/PHP/Bash used to work nicely together, but now there seems to be a disconnect between my new javascript and PHP. *Please note:* I am no longer using jQuery and prefer not to use it any longer for this project!

Here is what I've tested:

- The PHP code to run the bash script works in isolation (without the switch statement). My room lights turn on.
- I played with URI encoding, but it didn't seem to help.
- The javascript "main.js" can call "controller.php" just fine by requesting only "controller.php" while OMITTING any ?'s or variables (again, without the switch statement in my PHP code). My room lights turn on.
- Clicking the button in my HTML file runs the java as expected.

Do you have any ideas for me to try to make this work? I'd like to give several buttons different ID's to elicit different responses from the server eventually.

Thanks in advance!

---

This is what my basic HTML file contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Learning AJAX PHP</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<button id="lights" onClick="buttonSelect(this.id)">Toggle Lights now</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript file being called:

```
function buttonSelect(ButtonName){
   var URLtoSend = "controller.php";
   var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.open("POST", URLtoSend, true);
   xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xhttp.send("action= " + ButtonName);
   alert("Sending this data: " + ButtonName);
}
```

Finally, here is the PHP receiving the POST request:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
    $javacomm = $_POST["action"];
} else {
    break;
}

switch($javacomm){
    case "lights":
        $output=shell_exec("/var/www/scriptfiles/Button5 2>&1");
        break;
    case "lightsoff":
        echo "lights are going out\n";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Bad data!";
}

function lights() {
    $output = shell_exec("/var/www/scriptfiles/Button5 2>&1");
    exit;


?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems in code

1. you must set request header before `xhttp.send`

> xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

2. you didn't send any data to controller, your controller needs post with name action, so in you must send data xhttp.send(`"action= " + ButtonName`)
3. in `controller.php` you forgot to close function lights()  {**}**

not its work

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, knizer! A few of those typos I had were from  multiple different attempts at troubleshooting. I cleaned up the code with your suggestions, but still had no success :(  the adjustments are in the original post now also. Any other ideas where I might be going wrong still?

Comment: It works! Thanks, knizer. I had to remove the space after "action=" in your revision, but your answer helped otherwise. Another thing that helped me trouble shoot was some basic logging to see what was going on:
`$file = fopen("PHPlog","w");`
`echo fwrite($file,"action was set to $javacomm this time");`
`fclose($file);`